# How to properly plot the image converted to an array via img_to_array

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, keras

I would like to know how to properly plot the image converted into array via keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array.

Here is my naive approach. To give you minimum example, I download a duck picture from online:

```
import urllib.request

f = open('duck.jpg','wb')
f.write(requests.get('http://i.imgur.com/Ph4Xw.jpg').content)
f.close()
```

When I try to plot this before converting the img into numpy array, it works:

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img ,img_to_array
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
img = load_img('duck.jpg')

plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

The resulting plot looks like this: [image]

However, after I convert the image into array via numpy array via keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array, the plotting the array object does not look right:

```
arr_img = img_to_array(img)
plt.imshow(arr_img)
plt.savefig("duck2.jpg")
```

The resulting plot looks like this: [image]
Is there a way to correctly plot `arr_img`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found that all I had to do was devided arr_img by 255.

```
arr_img = img_to_array(img)
plt.imshow(arr_img/255)
plt.savefig("duck2.jpg")
```